# How can I pass multiple variables that are space seperated strings to a function in bash?

Tags: bash

Consider this mockup:

```
function test() { 
    for line in $1
    do
        echo $line
    done
    for line2 in $2
    do
        echo $line2
    done
}

# This will give me a list of IDs
list=$(find testfolder/ -type f -exec grep "ID" {} + | sed "s/^.*ID:\ //g")
list2=$(find testfolder2/ -type f -exec grep "ID" {} + | sed "s/^.*ID:\ //g")

# this will not work
test list1 list2

# this will work 
for line in $line
do
    echo $line
done
for line2 in $2
do
    echo $line
done
```

The problem with this is that the variables $1 and $2 in the function, will be (of course) the first two IDs that were retrieved in list.

Is there a way to pass list and list2 to the function and use them as I would in a non function call?

Comment: Use bash arrays. Or just pass them as text. I guess `for line in $line` `for line2 in $2` in `this will work` is a typo for `for line in $list` and `for line in $list2`.

Comment: Try like this `test "$list1" "$list2"`

Comment: @KamilCuk Could not get it to work with arrays. Yea that was a typo!

Comment: @Ivan Yea, nice! It worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with Shell scripting and file names is, that the shell splits the input stream into tokens by spaces and newlines. Which characters are used, is stored in the global variable `IFS`, which is the abbreviation for input field separator. The problem is, that file names may contain spaces and newlines. And if you do not quote the file names correctly as you did it in your question, then the file names get split by the shell.

#### Problem

Create some files with space:

```
$ touch a\ {1..3}
```

If you use a globing pattern to iterate the files, everything is fine:

```
$ for f in a\ *; do echo ►$f◄; done
►a 1◄
►a 2◄
►a 3◄
```

But when you use a sub-shell, which echos the file names, they get messed:

```
$ for f in $(echo a\ *); do echo ►$f◄; done
►a◄
►1◄
►a◄
►2◄
►a◄
►3◄
```

The same happens, when you use `find`:

```
$ for f in $(find . -name 'a *'); do echo ►$f◄; done
►./a◄
►2◄
►./a◄
►3◄
►./a◄
►1◄
```

#### Solution

The best way to read a list of files is to delimit them with a character, which is normally not in a file. This is the null character `$'\0'`. The program `find` has a special action called `-print0` to print the file name with a trailing null character. And the Bash function `mapfile` can read a list, which is delimited with null characters:

```
$ mapfile -d $'\0' list < <(find . -name 'a *' -print0)
```

Now you can write a function, which needs a list of file names.

```
$ inode() { for f in "$@"; do stat -c %i "$f"; done; }
```

And pass the list of file names correctly quoted to the function.

```
$ inode "${list[@]}"
2638642
2638644
2638641
```

And this works even with newlines in the file name.